# Getting Open Namespaces and Modules in an FSI Session

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Is there any way to retrieve a list of open namespaces and modules in an FSI Session? I'm playing around with printing an F# quoted expression and I'd like to be able to distinguish between those values of a module which should be printed fully qualified versus those which should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this.

The `fsi` object doesn't have any way of doing that, so the simple approach like this won't work. I believe that internally, the information is stored in the `FsiDynamicCompilerState` record that F# Interactive uses to keep current state of the interaction (you can find it in "fsi.fs" in the sources).

Unfortunatelly, I didn't find any static property that you could use to access this state - it is kept as a field in `FsiDynamicCompiler` which is created in the `main` function and not stored anywhere else. In principle, you may want to be able to access the instance via stack trace (but I couldn't find a way to get local variables of a stack frame).

If you wanted to modify `fsi.exe` to make this possible, that would be another question, but I suppose that's not what you want.

Comment: thanks for looking into this for me. You're right that modifying `fsi.exe` is not a viable option for this project, but I appreciate the suggestion since that would be a neat project of its own: it would be good to extract the core functionality into a library component so you could create and manipulate Sessions programmatically including building alternative GUI front-ends.